# Need to find the wrong output in the following python code

Tags: python

```
def max3bad(x,y,z):
  maximum = 0
  if x >= y:
    if x >= z:
      maximum = x
  elif y >= z:
   maximum = y
  else:
    maximum = z
 return(maximum)
```

wrong output for what input?
get an input for which u get wrong output

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why don't you just put the inputs into a list, sort the list, and return the last element of the sorted list?

Comment: Are you asking us what inputs will produce an incorrect output, or are you asking us to find a bug in this code?

Answer (score 0):

for case: x = 2, y = 1, z = 3
the code output is 0 not 3.

It's better to get max number by :

```
max(x, y, z)
```

or you fix bug in your code:

```
def max3bad(x,y,z):
  maximum = 0
  if x >= y:
    if x >= z:
      maximum = x
    else:
      maximum = z
  elif y >= z:
   maximum = y
  else:
    maximum = z
 return maximum
```